# Special Pairs in a Set Proof

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have a function that gets all the adjacent pairs plus a pair made of the last element and the first, e.g.

special_pairs([1,2,3]) = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)]

Suppose now that if a number $x$ appears in more than half of the elements of a list $A$, how can we prove that at least one of the pairs in special_pairs($A$) is $(x,x)$?

My gut feeling tells me this is similar to pigeon hole principle. Not sure where to start though.

Comment: I think what you're asking is, if you put a bunch of things in a circle, and more than half of those things are the same color, then two adjacent things will have the same color. It really doesn't make sense to say "$x$ appears in more than half of the elements of a set $A$," since by definition of *set*, all its elements are distinct.

Comment: Anyway, you could start by distinguishing between even and odd locations on the circle, or in the list, as in your edit. If more than half are $x$, they're either all the odd positions, or they are both positions in an odd-even pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try induction on $n$: if $n=2$ we are done; by assumption $A = [x,x]$. Now suppose the result holds for some $k$ and assume $A = [x_0,...,x_k]$ has $k+1$ elements, where more than $(k+1)/2$ of those elements equal $x$. Consider $A \upharpoonright k = [x_0,...,x_{k-1}]$. If $A \upharpoonright k$ contains more than $k/2$ elements that equal $x$, then we are done by the inductive hypothesis. The only special is the case when $k+1$ is odd, exactly $1 + k/2$ elements of $A$ equal $x$, and $x_k = x$ (Why?). Then $A \upharpoonright k$ contains as many elements that equal $x$ as it contains elements that do not equal $x$. If there is an adjacent pair in $A \upharpoonright k$, we are done. Otherwise, elements in $A \upharpoonright k$ must alternate. Recall $x_k = x$. So either $x_0 = x$ (and the pair $(x_k,x_0)$ is of the required form) or $x_0 \neq x$ and hence (by alternating) $x_{k-1} = x$ (and thus $(x_{k-1},x_k)$ does the trick).

Comment: Why would A \ k contain exactly as many elements equal to x as those not equal to x?

Comment: @Zexion12 If A has $2n + 1$ many elements, then by assumption of the special case $n+1$ of these equal $x$ (note this is the minimal case; if fewer elements equalled $x$ then your stated assumption that more than half the elements equal $x$ would fail). So if $x_k = x$ and we remove it we are left with $k = 2n$ elements of which $n+1-1=n$ equal $x$.

Comment: As usual with these things, try and plug in numbers to see what happens: suppose $k+1 = 3$ then $A = [x,y,x], [x,x,y]$ or $[y,x,x]$ to satisfy your requirement. (This would be the special case above, as if only one element equalled $x$ your hypothesis would fail). Take away the last element in the cases $[x,y,x]$ or $[y,x,x]$ (the remaining one trivially satisfies what you want). What is left?